# How to set a variable based on time/date

Tags: php

How can I set a variable, $a, to a specific value based on the day of the week and time of day.

For example, in pseudocode:

```
Mon 09.00h - 16.59h, $a = 5,
Sat 12.00h - 13.00h, $a = 10
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to know what the relevance of the end value is. For example, if one part of the day is always even or odd, if weekdays have one value vs weekends. Right now, your example is very simple to execute, but if there are, say, 25 possible values, there are better ways to derive the value than to use an increasingly complicated serious of conditional statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time = time()%86400;
$date = date("D");
// since 9 hours = 32400 seconds and 16 hours and 59 minutes = 61140 seconds
if($date == "Mon" && $time >= 32400 && $time <= 61140){
$a = 5;
}
// since 12 hours = 43200 seconds and 13 hours = 46800 seconds
else if($date == "Sat" && $time >= 43200 && $time <= 46800){
$a = 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I amend this to say "Mon" or "Tues"?

Comment: `if(($date == "Mon" || $date == "Tue") && $time >= 32400 && $time <= 61140)`.